# Why request is not transfer'd from hello.jsp to controller?

Tags: spring

I am new to MVC.

I am trying to build a simple hello world application using Spring MVC. 
I am getting 404 error as href doesn't goes to hello.jsp. I have my hello.jsp under my WEB-INf and index,jsp is under Web apps. Below is my code for the application. Thank you all in advance

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView mymethod(){
        return new ModelAndView("hello","msg","Hello First Spring");
    }
}
///////////////////////////   spring.xml ////////////////////////
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
/////////////////////////     web.xml      //////////////////////////////////
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
////////////////////////////   index.jsp     ////////////////////////////
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>

<%= java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime() %>

<a href="hello.jsp">click here</a>

</body>
</html>

     //////////////////////////// hello.jsp    /////////////////////////
    Message is: ${msg}]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUJ9j.png
```

Comment: Please at least reformat the question w.r.t. the link to the screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUJ9j.png (so people willing to help do not have to copy and paste.

Comment: @Rishibian did you change what i told you?

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to GET

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView mymethod(){
        return new ModelAndView("hello","msg","Hello First Spring");
    }
```

Also change your web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi Cralfaro, I tried but still I am getting same 404 error. I cannot call hello controller from hello.jsp

Comment: @RishibanR modify also the web.xml i added the code in the response